# How to remove deprecated fields in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have removed some fields from document definition. I want to remove this field across all documents of collection. How can I do it?

Comment: See [this highly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987289/how-to-remove-column-from-child-collection)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Try:

```
db.collection.update(
    { '<field>': { '$exists': true } },  // Query
    { '$unset': { '<field>': true  } },  // Update
    false,                               // Upsert
    true                                 // Multi-update
)
```

where `field` is your deprecated field and `collection` is the collection it was removed from.

The general update command is of the form `db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )`. The `false` and `true` trailing arguments disable upsert mode and enable multi update so that the query updates all of the documents in the collection (not just the first match).

**Update for MongoDB 2.2+**

You can now provide a JSON object instead of positional arguments for upsert and multi.

```
db.collection.update(
    { '<field>': { '$exists': true } },  // Query
    { '$unset': { '<field>': true  } },  // Update
    { 'multi': true }                    // Options
)
```

Comment: The value of specified for the value of the field in the $unset statement (i.e. 1 here) does not impact the operation. [$unset operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/unset/#_S_unset)

Answer (score 29):

just do something like this

```
db.people.find().forEach(function(x) {
   delete x.badField;
   db.people.save(x);
})
```

oooh the `$unset` answer someone gave using `update()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987289/how-to-remove-column-from-child-collection) is pretty awesome too.

Comment: Thx, Jamund. Your approach works too.

Comment: Cannot accept 2 answers. So just upvoted it.

Comment: Don't do it this way. This method will be extremely slow for large collections because it processes each item individually running multiple queries for each item.

Comment: This is useful pattern, but only when you need to do non-trivial updates that may require a complex processing of each of the documents.

Comment: This is also useful for when the $unset version is setting the field to null, and you want to remove the field completely.

Comment: Very useful since setting `x.badField = null;` doesn't wipe the field during save like my library does - it actually saves NULL

Comment: Still works in MongoDB version 2.6.1. Further, was able to update another field at the same time: `db.people.find().forEach(function(x) { delete x.badField; x.fieldToChange = "new value"; db.people.save(x); })`