# mongo db remove json objects

Tags: json, mongodb, deprecated, obsolete

I have a mongo json object as follows

```
{
  "_id" : new BinData(3, "RDHABb22XESWvP83FplqJw=="),
  "name" : "NEW NODE",
  "host" : null,
  "aet" : null,
  "studies" : ["1.3.12.2.1107.5.99.3.30000008061114424970500000589"],
  "testcases" : [new BinData(3, "Zhl+zIXomkqAd8NIkRiTjQ==")],
  "sendentries" : [{
     "_id" : "1.3.12.2.1107.5.99.3.30000008061114424970500000589",
     "Index" : 0,
     "Type" : "Study"
     }, {
      "_id" : "cc7e1966-e885-4a9a-8077-c3489118938d",
      "Index" : 1,
      "Type" : "TestCase"
    }]
}
```

The fields "Studies" and "TestCases" are now obsolete and I am now storing that information in a new field called SendEntries. I would like to get rid of the Studies and TestCases from the old entries and unmap those fields going forward. I want to know how I can update my current collections to get rid of the Studies and TestCases fields.

I'm just few weeks into Mongo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove deprecated fields in Mongo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641340/how-to-remove-deprecated-fields-in-mongo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator with update.

```js
db.collection.update({},
    { $unset: {
      "studies": "",
      "testcases": ""
    },
    { "upsert": false, "muti": true }
)
```

And that will remove all of the fields from all of your documents in your collection

Answer (score 0):

Use $unset, there's a [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) page e.g.

db.yourCollection.update( { },
                    { $unset: {
                                Studies: "",
                                testcases: ""
                              }
                    },
                    { multi: true }
                  )

Comment: Thank guys. I used $unset.

Using MongoVUE is probably a easy way for starters.

Just updating the way I solved it in MongoVUE
Select the collection you want to change, right click and select update.

In the "Enter Find Json" window type the following

{ "Field You want to delete": { $exists : true } }

Click count to find the number of instances.

In the 'Enter Update Json' put the following:
{ $unset : { "Field You want to delete" : "number of instances"} }

Hit update. If everything goes well your field should have disappeared.